# Confirmatory factor analysis for a newly constructed questionnaire

Tags: factor-analysis, psychometrics, scales

I am about to develop a new questionnaire with 142 questions I have performed exploratory factor analysis and 30 latent factors were extracted. I was wondering if it is **necessary** to perform **confirmatory factor analysis** for my newly constructed questionnaire too.

Comment: If I've understood correctly, you haven't developed the new questionnaire yet. What did you perform exploratory factor analysis on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Factor analysis at item or scale level?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69489/factor-analysis-at-item-or-scale-level)

Comment: Just as your other question, what you need to do depends on what you want to achieve. Asking what is “necessary” or what you “have to do” without a clear objective is not fruitful.