# Factor analysis at item or scale level?

Tags: factor-analysis

To develop a new questionnaire for measuring lifeguards' vigilance, after gathering data from different literature, I found 20 scales contributing to lifeguards' vigilance. Then I started to design questions for each scale in the way that in each scale, there are some questions (4 to 10 questions) with different face but with the same concept. Finally I have come up to 142 items. Now I want to perform factor analysis for construct validity. I don't know if I could perform FA at the scale level instead of item level. (Scales and items in each scale have face validity too.)

Comment: You need to explain what you want to learn from the factor analysis or why you are considering it. It's not an end in itself, you don't *have* to do it, at any level.

Comment: this is for construct validity of questionnaire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should perform factor analysis at the item level. In other words, you should input all of the items into a single factor analysis. This is assuming, of course, that you have enough cases (500+?). This would allow you to know what items measure what different constructs. Factor analysis at the scale level would be possible, but quite unorthodox. This might work if you have too few cases. This would assume that items within you scales all measure the same thing, which they likely do not, and this is what factor analysis is designed to test.

Comment: Why does FA of a separate scale `assume that items within your scale all measure the same thing`?

Comment: Well if you are doing FA on scales (rather than items), you are summing the items to calculate the scales. If you are summing items, then this assumes that each item generally measures the same construct. Consider a measure of depression (or anything, really), if you sum items, you are adding depression severity and it is assumed that every item measures depression severity.

Comment: i want to add an example to clarify the case. as i said i found 20 scales. one of these scales, for example, is concentration. for this scale i design 6 questions to cover different aspects of life guarding. these questions although designed for different aspect of life-guarding but all of them measure concentration and they all received face validity by experts . and i did the same with other scales. now when performing factor analysis 33 variables are extracted and those questions designed for concentration is distributed in different factors. what should i do now

Comment: dear ttnphns. yes. items within my scales all measure the same thing

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, but it appears that they measure slightly different things. Look at the items and see if they have anything in common.

Comment: @Behacad, I'm sorry, I mistook your phrase (I thought you were talking about doing FAs on items of each scale separetely).

Comment: @behacad, what if they measure the same things. for example:

Comment: @behacad, what if they measure the same things. for example:1. dangerous behavior of children make me anxious. and 2. the feeling that one day i might face an unconscious person under water make me anxious. these two questions although design for different situation but they measure the same construct. that is anxiety

Comment: That is the point of factor analysis, it empirically tells you whether they measure the same construct. Those might be the same construct (e.g., anxiety), or they might not. For example, children anxiety and underwater body anxiety may well best be conceptualized as distinct construct (despite both being anxiety-related).

Comment: then, how should i know these loaded items in different extracted factors are gathered due to substantive aspects of items and not just by statistical effects of scores

Comment: Well you can't know for sure why items load on certain factors versus others. Typically it is because of the content of items, but other factors, such as the visual placing of items and the wording of items, may also impact loadings. If no such factors are obvious, then the content of items (i.e., what construct they measure in common), is perhaps the best factor to interpret.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that confirmatory factor analysis (CFA) is typically run separately for each scale in order to verify the expected factor structure of each. If your intent is to use these scales as IVs and DVs in an analysis (e.g., multiple regression), I'd use this route. However, if your intention is to perform an exploratory factor analysis on all of your items across scales and search for "emergent" factors not intended by the original authors, I think an argument could be made for the latter approach.